List of all GCalendar recurrence dates with GScript
I try to create a simple list in GScript from all my recurrence dates in GCalendar. Currently, all appointments are displayed. However, I would only list the initial appointment with the appointment data: subject, appointment time, appointment end, interval.
Does anyone have a scriptexample wo can this explain my mistake in the script?
Many thanks
function Stackoverflow() {
  var calendarId = CalendarApp.getId();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var events = calendar.getEvents(new Date(1901-01-01), new Date('2099-12-31'));

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('MyCalendar');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow(['Subject', 'Start', 'End', 'Intervall']);

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    if (event.isRecurringEvent()) {
      var startDate = event.getStartTime();
      var endDate = event.getEndTime();
      var myPeriod = event.isRecurringEvent().valueOf
      sheet.appendRow([event.getTitle(), startDate, endDate]);
    }
  }

  Logger.log('Tabelle erstellt: ' + spreadsheet.getUrl());
}


isRecurringEvent() tests if an event is part of a series. Since the code evaluates every event, isRecurringEvent() is "true" for every instance of a recurrent event. part of an event series => Class CalendarEventSeries and the Advanced Calendar Service &/or Calendar API. Google Apps Script: Calendar Service: Find first event in CalendarEventSeries should help.

Read the notes on getId() for the Calendar Event Series. The different Ids is the key to understanding how to find a series vs an event.
